# How to get which button submitted the form on ASP .NET page inside FormView Inserted/Updated events

Tags: asp.net

I have two buttons on ASP .NET form: **Save** and **Save & Return**. If user hits **Save & Return** I would like to save data etc. and go to another page. If user hits **Save** I want to stay on current page.

But I don't know how to get information which button was clicked inside Updated/Inserted event of FormView. Is there a chance to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the ItemCommand event of FormView to save the reference of pressed button.

```
LinkButton btn;
protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    btn = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
 }
protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    if (btn.Text == "Save")
         e.KeepInInsertMode = true;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get that values inside ItemUpdated / ItemInserted event handler?